# Nested SQL Joins in MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, nested

I normalized my data and have been trying to display data across multiple tables. I'm fairly new to SQL, so please bear with me.

What I'm trying to do is display tasks that haven't been assigned to a project yet, but contain data from various tables such as project title, company, etc (Using a LEFT JOIN and a WHERE clause).

The original code which works:

```
SELECT Tasks.ID, Projects_Tasks.ProjectID
FROM Tasks LEFT JOIN Projects_Tasks ON Projects_Tasks.TaskID = Tasks.ID
WHERE Projects_Tasks.ProjectID IS NULL;
```

The nested joins code (that doesn't work):

```
SELECT Tasks.ID, Projects.ProjectTitle, ProjectManagers.FirstName, ProjectManagers.LastName, Companies.Company
FROM ((((Tasks
LEFT JOIN Projects_Tasks ON Projects_Tasks.TaskID = Tasks.ID)
INNER JOIN Projects_Tasks ON Projects_Tasks.ID = Projects.ID)
INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.ID = Projects_Tasks.ProjectID)
INNER JOIN ProjectManagers ON ProjectManagers.ID = Projects.ProjectManagerID)
INNER JOIN Companies ON Companies.ID = ProjectManagers.CompanyID
WHERE Projects_Tasks.ProjectID IS NULL;
```

I've tried numerous combinations, but I just can't get it to work. I've tried reversing the order of my nested joins (in case it executes from bottom to top) and I've tri

Comment: My I ask why are you nesting these joins?

Comment: It looks like the table you are left joining to `Projects_Tasks` you are also inner joining to..

Comment: Please elaborate on *"doesn't work"*. Also something seems to be missing from your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't enjoy writing SQL statements.The good thing about Access though is it can make your SQL statements for you in Queries

Using Query Builder:

- Select the tables Project_Tasks & Project_Managers & all other tables
  you want to display data
- Select all the relevant data fields you want to display
- Where you have the 'ProjectID' field, the Criteria section needs to have "Is Null" (don't put the quotation marks though)

Then, save the query, and run it. (You can probably just use that query, or otherwise strip out the SQL statement)

Good luck!